# Barra de progreso animada [HTML,CSS,JAVASCRIPT]

Tags: javascript, html, progressbar

estoy intentando hacer una barra de progreso que se mueva dependiendo de qué imagen este activa en el carousel.

Estoy utilizando un carousel de bootstrap y se van alternando entre 3 imagenes, la imagen que está mostrándose contiene el atributo "class='active'" y este va cambiando según cambian las imágenes. He creado un script con Javascript que consigue esto pero no cambia, es decir, toma el primer valor y así se queda. Os dejo todo el código completo para ver si me podéis echar una mano que sería de gran ayuda.

```
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="carousel slide" id="carouselExampleIndicators" data-ride="carousel">
          <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar bg-danger" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%" aria-valuenow="100" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
          </div>
          <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            
            <img src="assets/img/banner1.jpg" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active">
            <img src="assets/img/banner2.jpg" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1">
            <img src="assets/img/banner3.jpg" data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="2">
            
            <a href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="prev">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><</button>
            </a>
            <a href="#carouselExampleIndicators" role="button" data-slide="next">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">></button>
            </a>
          </ol>
          <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="carousel-item active">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/banner1.jpg" alt="First slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/banner2.jpg" alt="Second slide">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img class="d-block w-100" src="assets/img/banner3.jpg" alt="Third slide">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--Scripts para funcionalidades Bootstrap-->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
  let imagenActiva = document.querySelector("img[class='active']");
  let posicion = imagenActiva.getAttribute("data-slide-to");
  let barraProgreso = document.querySelector("div[class='progress-bar bg-danger']");

  if(posicion==0)
  {
    barraProgreso.style = "width: 33%";
  }
  else if(posicion==1)
  {
    barraProgreso.style = "width: 66%";
  }
  else{
    barraProgreso.style = "width: 100%";
  }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: para cambiar el css desde javascript lo tienes que hacer así `barraProgreso.style.width = "33%";`

Comment: Lo acabo de probar y funciona igual de las dos maneras, el problema es que cuando la imagen pase y se cambie el atributo active no se va a volver a ejecutar el script. Es ahí a donde quiero llegar.

Comment: ah vale. Creo que para que se ejecute tu código por cada cambio de imagen tienes que escuchar el evento click en los botones de prev y next. Y ahi validar la posición activa + 1 para saber la siguiente y actualizar la barra.

Comment: Lo intentaré para que cambie con los botones, pero la cosa es que las imagenes cambian solas.